# Need to write SQL Server stored procedure to save one or more rows based on time calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I need to write a function that rounds time in one column, called StartTime, to display just the hour and insert it to another column called StartHour.  In another column, called EndTime, I also need to use DATEPART to round up to the next incremented hour (ex: 23:33:00.0000000 would be 23 (the hour) + 1 (to round it up to the end hour) = 24 and I would need to save that to the EndHour column).

I want to insert these new values into new columns called StartHour and StartMinute, EndHour, and EndMinute (the StartTime and EndTime columns are the **original values** I'm working with in time(7) format and for historical purposes, I'm keeping them in their original columns).

Here's what I have so far in T-SQL:

```
SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, [StartTime])) AS StartHour,(DATEPART(MINUTE, [StartTime])) AS StartMinute,
(DATEPART(HOUR, [EndTime])) AS EndHour, 
(DATEPART(MINUTE, [EndTime])) AS EndMinute, StartTime, EndTime
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Outage_Reports]
  ORDER BY OutageDate ASC
```

Which produces:

```
StartHour   StartMinute   EndHour       EndMinute      Startime          EndTime
16        0                 17       30            16:00:00    17:30:00
```

**I now need to write this conversion into a stored procedure that also inserts two (or more if the outage goes on for several hours) new rows into the table when the length between start and end is more than one hour.  Or just inserts one row when the outage was below or equal to an hour.  And then I need to account for that hourly progression in the start and end columns.**  Like this:

```
 StartHour   StartMinute    EndHour     EndMinute        Startime        EndTime
      16          0             17            00         16:00:00         17:30:00
```

(the above reflects the first hour of outage, the second row below reflects the second half hour of the outage until it stopped...both will be tied to the same outage ticket in the table)

```
    StartHour     StartMinute    EndHour    EndMinute    Startime      EndTime  
   17             30             18          00  16:00:00      17:30:00
```

The idea is to track website outages hour by hour so they can join to an orders table that tracks orders by hour (and the orders never contain minutes...just hours).  So the plan is to make two rows for an outage that goes on for 1.5 hours so the 16, 17 and all the way through the rounded up 18 hourly values can be tied to the orders table with the 30 minute column to act as another point of calculation (so an hour and a half would equal a full hour's worth of orders plus a half hour's worth of orders...split out row by row).  This way I can better track trends during outages.

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to write this logic to a stored procedure.  I would conceivably have to declare the new hour and minute values into variables and for the StartHour column always keep it rounded to the DATEPART hour value (even if it was 16:45...I want to insert 16 into the StartHour column).  However, with the EndHour column, I want to insert **a rounded up hourly value** (17 and then 18 because we went over an hour in that case) **into the EndHour column**.   This would hopefully describe (via these two rows) the close to two hours the outage occurred.  And in turn it would allow for an easy join to our orders table

Any guidance on a stored procedure for this logic would be appreciated.

Comment: If an outage ends *exactly* on the hour (some chance, I know, but maybe even within the first minute of the hour), do you still round up to the next hour? Also, do you have to deal with outages that span across midnight?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.  If it begins at 3:00 and the outage begins at 3:01...we would record it as StartHour 3 and EndHour 4 and then use the minutes of duration (this is a separate calc I'll be doing) to determine length.  We then apply that calculation to the amount of orders.  All I need for now is to know how to get the outage length, hour by hour, into the table.  Thanks!

Comment: For my first question, I meant - if the outage starts at 2:45, and *ends* at 3:00, do we insert one row (2-3) or two rows (2-3 and 3-4)?

Comment: If it happens as you outline in your comment here....it would be a one row insert.  IF it went from 2:45 to 3:01...it's a two row insert. If it's 2:45 to 4:01....it's a three row insert....StartHours would be 2 (EndHour 3), 3 (EndHour 4) AND 4 (EndHour at 5) in the third row...

I know it may sound a but crazy, but my boss came up with the logic and I am a fledgling BI developer and I respect him, so I just want to follow his logic here.  Does my explanation help here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i didn't really understand the purpose!!
but the logic may be something like as below---

```
declare @StartTime time
declare @EndTime time
declare @Temp_StartTime time

declare @temp_StartHour int
declare @temp_EndHour int
declare @temp_StartMinute int
declare @temp_EndMinute int

SET @StartTime='2:30:00'
SET @EndTime='4:01:00'
SET @Temp_StartTime=@StartTime

SET @temp_StartHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndHour=DATEPART(HOUR, @EndTime)
SET @temp_StartMinute=DATEPART(MI, @StartTime)
SET @temp_EndMinute=DATEPART(MI, @EndTime)

if(@temp_EndMinute>0)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp_EndHour=@temp_EndHour+1
    END

DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE
(
  StartHour int,
  StartMinute int,
  EndHour int,
  EndMinute int,
  StartTime time,
  EndTime time
)

WHile((@temp_EndHour-@temp_StartHour>=1))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Temp_Table
        SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartHour,(DATEPART(MINUTE, @Temp_StartTime)) AS StartMinute,
        @temp_StartHour+1 AS EndHour, 
        0 AS EndMinute, @StartTime as StartTime, @EndTime as EndTime

        SET @temp_StartHour=@temp_StartHour+1
        SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(HOUR,1,@Temp_StartTime)

        if(DATEPART(MI, @Temp_StartTime)!=0)
            BEGIN
                SET @Temp_StartTime=DATEADD(MI,-@temp_StartMinute,@Temp_StartTime)
            END
    END

SELECT * FROM @Temp_Table
```

hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!  I will test this out and let you know soon.  And as to the purpose, like I said, the logic is my boss's.  I kind of get why he wants it done this way, but I realize it sounds a bit strange if you're not familiar with our system.

Comment: It worked great. Thanks!!  Now that I can see how you did it, I'm able to further define the logic and add to it.